# Is there a library available to workaround out of date timezone data?

Tags: android, timezone

Since timezone data (e.g. Olson timezone database) on Android is only updated with a system update and such system updates on Android are frustratingly few and far between, there is a very real possibility that devices "in the wild" will have out of date timezone data.  This becomes a major problem for applications that need to be able to show accurate times in different locations around the world.

Are there any libraries or other third-party tools out there that can be used to fix timezone data on devices with out of date information?

I am aware of the possibility for [updating the timezone data manually on a rooted device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1324935), but I am looking for a solution that can be integrated into an app and that will require no additional effort from the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Joda-Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) when i was having problem with timezone settings.

check the **org.joda.time.DateTimeZone** class

Here is the API documentation for the [same](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html).

Comment: This seems to be a good approach.  I just wish there were some way to get that data withtout including the whole ~600k jar file.  Ugh.